# Constexpr evaluation and compiler optimization level

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

see the following snippet:

```
struct config {
    int x;

    constexpr int multiply() const {
        return x*3;
    }
};

constexpr config c = {.x = 1};

int main() {
    int x =  c.multiply();
    return x;
}
```

If I compile this with clang and -O0 I get a function call to multiply even though the object c and the function are marked constexpr. If I compile it with -O1 everything gets optimized as expected. Gcc on the other hand generates no call to multiply.

If I change the main to:

```
int main() {
    constexpr auto y = c.multiply();
    int x =  y;
    return x;
}
```

If I compile this with clang and -O0 I get not function call and the value 3 directly as stack variable. The -O1 result is the same as above.

So my question is: Does the constexpr evaluation depend on the compiler level? I would expect that in the example 1 the call to multiply would be constexpr and performed compile time. (like gcc does)

BR,
go2sh

See https://godbolt.org/z/WvPE5W77h

Comment: `constexpr` is not a tool for optimization. It is a tool for doing things that *have to be* done at compile-time, for generating data that the compiler will use to compile further C++ code. Like filling out template parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Standard just requires that a call to `constexpr` is evaluated at compile time if the arguments are `constexpr` and the result must be `constexpr` due to context. Basically just forcing more restrictions on the author of the function, thus allowing it to be used in `constexpr` contexts.

Meaning `y` in second snippet forces evaluation at compile time. On the other hand, `x` in the first is an ordinary run-time call.

**But the as-if rule applies here** - as long as the observable effects of the program remain the same, the compiler can generate any instructions it wants. It can evaluate any function, even non-`constexpr` ones if it can do so - happens in practice often with constants propagation.

Yes, in general, higher optimization levels will inline more code and push more evaluation to the compile time. But "looking at the assembly" is not an observable effect in the sense above so there are no guarantees. You can use `inline` to give a hint for inlining the function instead of calling it (`constexpr` is inline by default but for other reasons...) but the compilers can ignore them.

Of course, the compiler can evaluate all `constexpr` functions with `constexpr` args at compile time, that is why they exist, why clang does not do so with `-O0`, I do not know.

If you need guaranteed compile-time evaluation, use `consteval` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A bit more background. I'm working in an embedded space, and I want to make sure, that as much as possible is done during compile time to ease on performance and code size. So whenever I really want something constexpr, I'll specify it. I thought compiler would implicitly always use the constexpr path. On the otherhand for debugging purposes it might be good to call the function to observe the behaviour.

Comment: @go2sh In that case just store/use the result always in `constexpr` variable/context. No, the compiler doesn't have to. Not sure what were the reasons for not forcing it.